# Mac terminal showing operation not permitted

Tags: macos, terminal

I opened the terminal and tried to type in the commands but the terminal is showing the message

```
login: -h option: operation not permitted [Process completed].
```

How to solve the problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How are you opening terminal? Have you made any changes? For what it's worth, the Login option `-h` is only allowed for root/super-user, hence the error on a non-root shell. How that happened for you is beyond me.

Answer (score -1):

Check this [link out](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).

Can you try running this and rebooting and see if it works after that?

```
csrutil disable
```